# Showing values when you know the key in AngularJS

Tags: arrays, json, angularjs

I have the variable:

```
$scope.rolesData = [{id : '1', name : 'user'}, {id : '2', name : 'superuser'},{id : '3', name : 'admin'}];
```

And I got from a DB an user object with integer value, which tells me what is the role. It is from 1 to 3. user.userRole is 1,2 or 3.

```
$scope.users = adminUserSvc.query(); //From DB
```

Everything is workin fine in select:

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in users">
...
<select class="form-control" ng-model="user.userRole" ng-options="role.id as role.name for role in rolesData">
</select>
```

But I wonder how I can show the same  inside the {{}}? If I know that user.userRole is giving me id 1, how the heck I'll get the value of name?

This is inside the ngRepeat:

```
<div ng-hide="editingUsers[user.userId]">{{rolesDataSOMETHING??}}</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok you can use this:

```
{{(rolesData | filter:{id:user.userRole})[0].name}}
```

At first it filters the rolesData Object - then gets the first object (it should only be one because of the filter) with `[0]`.

---

**Old Answer (to old question):**

You just need to save the right 'thing' in your model by changing your `ng-options`!

```
ng-options="role as role.name for role in rolesData"
```

This will save the whole role object `{id : '1', name : 'user'}` in your `user.userRole` model, to output the name just use `{{user.userRole.name}}`

There is no need for ngRepeat here.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't tell you that this user.userRole is coming from DB and there is only int from 1 to 3.

Comment: sorry can you explain it better? do you set ``user.userRole`` on your ``$scope`` from DB?

Comment: No. I have a list of users in scope which I got from DB. Then I use ng-repeat for showing every user in a list. Every user is modifiable.

Comment: YES :) I just know the integer and I create a another json-list for just user interface purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You could use lodash (http://lodash.com) to find the element you are looking for. You'd probably want to put that in a function on your controller. Something like

```
$scope.getName = function(id) {
  var i = _.findIndex($scope.rolesData, { id: id });
  return $scope.rolesData[i].name;
}
```

And then in your template, you could reference this in the brackets like:

```
<div ng-hide="edingUsers[user.userId]">{{getName(user.userRole)}}
```